# Memtest freezing beyond 4G, but individual RAM sticks all pass

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios, hardware-failure

I'm investigating an issue on a machine that has 4 identical pieces of DDR-3 RAM, each with 4 GB capacity. It has been suffering from sudden unrecoverable freezes (observed on Linux), so I started to test RAM with Memtest86.

Some experimenataion shows that:

- Any of the four RAM sticks used alone passes Memtest (= no failure found after ~1 hour of running).
- When using any combination of 2-4 sticks, no matter which ones, Memtest freezes within seconds. In particular, it freezes during the "address test" when checking the range of 6G-8G.
- When I set an upper limit of 4G in the Memtest configuration, it also passes.

What I've tried to mitigate the issue, all with no success:

- Reset the BIOS to default settings
- Slightly increase RAM voltage to from the vendor-specified 1.5 V to 1.55 V
- Decrease RAM frequency from 1333 MHz to 800 MHz

It appears that somehow, addressing memory beyond 4G somehow fails terribly. Does this indicate failure of some particular piece of hardware, e.g. the mainboard? Or is it some BIOS setting that's wrong? Are there any further steps I could take to narrow down the source?

Comment: Could be an issue with hardware (gfx card? NIC? NVme SSD) mapping itself into that memory in some weird way. Did this start happening after a hardware change and/or firmware/bios update? I would test with the absolute minimum attached to the motherboard. If possible also test the RAM on another, known good, system.

Comment: I did add 2 additional (identical) RAM sticks to the 2 already in place before, otherwise nothing changed. But the weird thing is that even with the 2 previous ones the problem occurrs. I'm not sure if it happened already before, because the machine has not been regularly used for a while.

Comment: Are you using the latest BIOS? Have you checked the PSU?

Comment: Yes, upgraded the BIOS to the latest version, no difference. I'm not sure how I could check the PSU (I don't have a good replacement).

Comment: Perhaps try the two original sticks but decrease the voltage, checking with one stick how low you can go.

Comment: How would decreasing voltage solve the issue; wouldn't it make latencies even worse?

Comment: @CedricReichenbach Hi, looks like I'm having this issue as well.  My computer runs a Minecraft Server and BOINC processing 24/7.  I did recently change the video card.  Have you been able to resolve this issue yet?

Comment: @BPugh Indeed, but in my case there was no actual hardware issue, just two separate issues with graphics drivers and Memtest itself. I've added an answer with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while, I was able to resolve this. It turns out there were multiple issues:

### The actual cause for crashes

The stability issues on Linux were unrelated to RAM. I figured this out by memory tests from within the OS using `memtester`, rather than Memtest86+ directly. There were no failures whatsoever that way.

Eventually, I figured out that switching graphics driver (I think from Nouveau to Nvidia, but maybe also vice versa) made the system stable. Why Nouveau caused a crash is still unclear to me.

### If memory is pristine, why does Memtest86+ freeze?

Most likely there's a bug with Memtest causing it to freeze under certain circumstances, but that's difficult to track down. There is [a launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/memtest86+/+bug/1876157) which describes very similar issues with Memetest86+ that's shipped with recent Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 1):

The symptom I had was that the PC booted normally and then after some 10 minutes rebooted on its own. After that, Ubuntu boot process did not finish but it always rebooted during the boot process.

### Memtest86

memtest86+ on Ubuntu 20.04 froze whenever more than one 4 GiB RAM stick was plugged in. Always at

```
Test #2: [Address test, own address Parallel]
Testing 4096M - 6144M
```

All sticks on their own did not lead to freezes.

It turned out that the memtest86 shipped by ubuntu has problems. I downloaded the latest BIOS-capable version 4.3.7 from memtest86.com and that one did not freeze.

The RAM was ok!

### Culprit

I unplugged the graphics card (MSI R7 370) and tried the on-board graphics unit, and that worked.
So it seems that the graphics card is somehow broken (while it worked in VGA mode), and causes the system to crash as soon as the Ubuntu boot process initializes it.